# Force line-height to equal height

Tags: html, css

I have a div element, the title element, with a variable height greater than its line-height due to sibling elements:

```
<div class="t-row t-flex t-divide">
    <div class="um-title">Manage Users</div>
        <div>
            <select class="t-input></select>
            <input type="text" class="t-input">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to make the line-height automatically assume the value of height?

Also, the text inside the div is currently aligned with the top and changing the vertical-align style doesn't have any effect; is there a way to align the text to the bottom if it's a flex item?

Comment: What does your corresponding css look like?

Comment: No, with plain css - line-height is ONLY relative the the element's font size.